# CSS for star rating system

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a 5 star system that displays the amount of stars you hover on.

So, there is a background, it has a width of 5 stars, then in front of it there is an identically shaped div that has a 5 different coloured stars, the width of this div by default is 0.

When a person hovers their cursor on the widths, the second background appears by adjusting the width properly.

I cannot get this to work, this is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AAgU9/

My html is:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div class="stb"></div>
    <div class="stf"></div>
    <div class="sts st1"></div>
    <div class="sts st2"></div>
    <div class="sts st3"></div>
    <div class="sts st4"></div>
    <div class="sts st5"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.stb{
     background:red;
    width:140px;
    height:27px;
    cursor:pointer}
.stf{
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    height:27px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:green 0 -26px;
    cursor:pointer}
.sts{
    position:absolute;
    width:28px;
    height:27px;
    top:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:2}
.st1{left:0}
.st2{left:28px}
.st3{left:56px}
.st4{left:84px}
.st5{left:112px}
.st1:hover .stf{background:red}
.st2:hover .stf{width:56px}
.st3:hover .stf{width:84px}
.st4:hover .stf{width:112px}
.st5:hover .stf{width:140px}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .st5:hover .stf will target the descendants div.stf of div.st5, but stf is actually a sibling of st5.

Comment: your `.st1:hover .stf` et al ... you don't have any children of `.st1`, how can those rules work?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/examples/StarRating/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/AAgU9/4/

You're using your selectors incorrectly. `.st1:hover .stf` will target descendants of `.st1:hover` with a class of `stf`. You have no such elements.

Instead, you want to look at siblings and, specifically, you want to use `~` which targets siblings that come after some element, meaning something like `#someElem ~ div` would select all div elements that are siblings of `#someElem` but also come after it.

So, just re-order your HTML:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div class="stb"></div>
    <div class="sts st1"></div>
    <div class="sts st2"></div>
    <div class="sts st3"></div>
    <div class="sts st4"></div>
    <div class="sts st5"></div>
    <div class="stf"></div>
</div>
```

and use `~` in your css:

```
.st1:hover ~ .stf {
    width: 28px;
}
.st2:hover ~ .stf {
    width:56px;
}
.st3:hover ~ .stf {
    width:84px;
}
.st4:hover ~ .stf {
    width:112px;
}
.st5:hover ~ .stf {
    width:140px;
}
```

some readin': http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind using jQuery? Hope this code will help you in the right direction:

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AAgU9/3/)

**CSS**

```
#stars_container {
background:#ddd;
background-width:0;
position:absolute:
top:0;
left:0;
display:block;
height:12px;
width:0;
}


.sts { display:inline; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="stars_container"></div>

<div class="sts" data-stars="10">1</div>
<div class="sts" data-stars="20">2</div>
<div class="sts" data-stars="30">3</div>
<div class="sts" data-stars="40">4</div>
<div class="sts" data-stars="50">5</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".sts").hover(function() {
  var len = $(this).data('stars');
  $("#stars_container").css({'width':len+'px'});
});
```

Comment: jQuery is fine, if there is no other method, although I was hoping I could keep this CSS only